# What's the start and stop location in memory for an application?

Tags: c#

I've written a loop that loops from 0x00000000 to 0x7FFFFFFF, but I think this is wrong. First of it takes for ages even to reach 1% when im looping thru this interval:

```
for (uint adr = 0x00000000; adr <= 0x7FFFFFFF; adr++)
{
...
}
```

I mentioned it before, but is 0x00000000 correct start value and what about stop value? My test app that I'm trying to read is taking up 388kB, is 0x7FFFFFFF the correct value to use?

**EDIT:**
The testapplication im trying to read is written by myself in c++ and contains only a int, with the value of `10`

Im trying to read the testapps memory with c#

Comment: You don't manage memory manually in C#. I assume Windows is allocating additional memory to your application as you ask for it. You can't just *guess* what your application's memory addresses are going to be.

Comment: Your loop will iterate from 0x00000000 to 0x7FFFFFFF inclusive.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? (Regardless, finding the module location for your C# code is a sensible question though.)

Comment: Uh, you can only read your own process address space unless you attach with debug privs, etc. Are you running the C# code in the same process as the C++ code? And are you trying to do this cooperatively (e.g. you can set up shared memory for IPC) or without the other process's cooperation?

Comment: So, are you trying to, from a C# application, find the memory location of another application, itself written in C++, based on a single 32-bit value...?

Comment: I see... So we're missing a lot of code here. This is not the normal way of accessing a variable from another application... Why exactly are you trying to do this by looping through memory locations?

Comment: Calling ReadProcessMemory on every byte/int a 2Gb address space (regardless of how much memory the app is actually using) is going to be slow. Expect it to take its time. At least read in bigger chunks, like a page - 4096 bytes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My test app [...] is taking up 388kB, is 0x7FFFFFFF the correct value to use?

Those 2 numbers are totally unrelated.

And whatever you're trying to do inside the loop is probably wrong.

Answer (score 1):

0x7fffffff hex is 2,147,483,647 decimal - looping more than 2 billion times might take a while ...

Answer (score 1):

Scanning through memory one byte at a time can take a while.

I suggest first stepping by `4` rather than by `1`, as x86 CPUs are way better at aligned memory accesses. Look at everything through the lens of four bytes at a time, and it'll doubtless run *way* faster than just four times faster.

Second, I suggest trying to find some mechanism to discover what the process memory map *looks like*. I'm not sure what the procedure is under windows; [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) may be a good first start. Under Linux, it'd just be reading from `/proc/self/maps`:

```
$ cat /proc/self/maps
00400000-0040b000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 701781                             /bin/cat
0060a000-0060b000 r--p 0000a000 08:03 701781                             /bin/cat
0060b000-0060c000 rw-p 0000b000 08:03 701781                             /bin/cat
006a9000-006ca000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f46fb0ca000-7f46fb36e000 r--p 00000000 08:03 489906                     /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
7f46fb36e000-7f46fb4e8000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 228784                     /lib/libc-2.12.1.so
7f46fb4e8000-7f46fb6e7000 ---p 0017a000 08:03 228784                     /lib/libc-2.12.1.so
7f46fb6e7000-7f46fb6eb000 r--p 00179000 08:03 228784                     /lib/libc-2.12.1.so
7f46fb6eb000-7f46fb6ec000 rw-p 0017d000 08:03 228784                     /lib/libc-2.12.1.so
7f46fb6ec000-7f46fb6f1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f46fb6f1000-7f46fb711000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 228792                     /lib/ld-2.12.1.so
7f46fb8f1000-7f46fb8f4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f46fb90f000-7f46fb911000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f46fb911000-7f46fb912000 r--p 00020000 08:03 228792                     /lib/ld-2.12.1.so
7f46fb912000-7f46fb913000 rw-p 00021000 08:03 228792                     /lib/ld-2.12.1.so
7f46fb913000-7f46fb914000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fffe4f02000-7fffe4f23000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fffe4f5d000-7fffe4f5e000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

You can see in my little output that the clear majority of address space is in fact empty; as it will probably be for your application too, since two gigabytes is a huge amount of memory for simple tasks. :) Yay.

Restricting your loop to just what is actually mapped for your process would avoid inevitable segmentation violation errors when you try to access memory that *isn't* mapped.